# Merge multiple csv files in python 3

Tags: python, csv, merge, python-3.6

I'm new to python and working on analyzing large data sets which involved merging csv files, they all contain the same labeled rows but with different amounts of columns. I don't have much but this is my current code, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
file1 = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Ubiome csv Kit #\\107-078-414.csv'
file2 = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Ubiome csv Kit #\\109-080-426.csv'

reader1 = csv.reader(open(file1))
reader2 = csv.reader(open(file2))

reader1 = csv.reader(open(file1))
reader2 = csv.reader(open(file2))
```

Comment: Merge how? What do the files look like? What are you trying to do with them? You haven't really shown us anything other than trivially loading the files...

Answer (score 0):

From the pandas docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2)
merged_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1, join = 'outer')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pymysql.cursors
import re
import csv
import collections
import glob

# Variables

total_record = []
headerCount = 0

for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    print(file)

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        list_record = list(reader)
        if headerCount == 0:
            headerCount = 1
            total_record.extend(list_record)
        else:
            list_record.pop(0)
            total_record.extend(list_record)

with open('combine.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerows(total_record)
```